# org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback;

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm using Jdbc template to insert a record into database. Below is the sql statement that results in an error.

```
INSERT INTO table_name(PDDID, APPLICATION_CODE, STATUS,CREATED_TS) VALUES ( ?,?,?,SYSTIMESTAMP)
```

Detail message is:

```
PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [

                    INSERT INTO table_name(PDDID, APPLICATION_CODE, STATUS,CREATED_TS) VALUES ( ?,?,?,SYSTIMESTAMP)

        ]
```

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback;   bad SQL grammar [ INSERT INTO table_name
>   (PDDID, APPLICATION_CODE, STATUS,CREATED_TS) VALUES (
>   ?,?,?,SYSTIMESTAMP)]; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "PDDID": invalid
>   identifier

Comment: What is the DDL of the table. You don't seem to have a column `PDDID`, maybe it is `pddid` instead (in which case you need to use `"pddid"` in your query)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you must enter a valid column name as it is either missing or the one entered is invalid. The "invalid identifier" most common happens when you are referencing an invalid alias in a select statement.  The Oracle docs note this on the ORA-00904 error:

ORA-00904 string: invalid identifier

Cause: The column name entered is either missing or invalid.

Enter a valid column name. A valid column name must begin with a letter, be less than or equal to 30 characters, and consist of only alphanumeric characters and the special characters $, _, and #.

If it contains other characters, then it must be enclosed in double quotation marks. It may not be a reserved word.
To avoid ORA-00904, column names cannot be a reserved word, and must contain these four criteria to be valid:

begin with a letter
be less than or equal to thirty characters
consist only of alphanumeric and the special characters ($_#); other characters need double quotation marks around.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the column name "PDDID" is correct.
Can you try running this statement directly on a DB client after replacing '?'s with valid values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your pddid field or use "pddid" , may it is conflicting with SQL pid.

Comment: Given this is Oracle, quoting would be done with double quotes, not with a backtick (which is a MySQL specific deviation from the SQL standard).